# How to deserialize JSON and map it to an string object

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

I'm new to JSON deserialization and scratching my head looking for a solution. I have searched numerous solutions online but none of them serves my purpose.

I have this example JSON data that I get from a webserver:

```
[943533322,"2016-06-23 02:34:38","1.1","gsQA-telem-pin-test-00","defaultTitleIdType","defaultReleaseT","defaultBuildVersion","14.1.3","2016-06-23 03:34:38","8037412060430813886","pc","telem_test","159.153.136.116","defaultMac","default","{\"defaultCSH\":[{\"defaultCSH1\":1},{\"defaultCSH2\":2}]}","defaultLevel","boot_start",0,"defaultPlayerIdType","defaultPlayerId","2016-06-23 03:34:38","defaultDOB","defaultExperimentId","{\"defaultPIDM\":[{\"defaultPIDM1\":1},{\"defaultPIDM3\":4}]}","{\"defaultDIDM\":[{\"defaultDIDM1\":2},{\"defaultDIDM3\":4}]}",null,"{\"status\":\"boot_start_event\",\"custom\":{\"defaultCEH\":[{\"defaultCEH1\":1},{\"defaultCEH2\":2}]}}",16975,"{\"x-ea-game-id-type\":\"\\\"defaulttitleidtype\\\"\",\"x-ea-taxv\":\"\\\"1.1\\\"\",\"x-ea-env\":\"\\\"test\\\"\",\"x-ea-game-id\":\"\\\"gsqa-telem-pin-test-00\\\"\",\"x-ea-uid\":null,\"x-ea-app-type\":null,\"application-id\":null}"]
```

I want to deserialize the values to an object of type string in this format:

```
 id | serverTS | taxv | tid | tidt | rel | v | sdkv | ts_post | s_id | plat | et | clientIP | mac | loc | custom | lev | en | s | pidt | pid | ts_event | dob | exid | pidm | didm | event_custom | event_params | dt_part | http_header
```

All the examples I have looked online are for JSON in the format of

```
{
   "id":"943533322",

   "serverTS":"2016-06-23 02:34:38",

   ...

}
```

But how do I deserialize JSON that is in the format

```
[

  "943533322",

  "2016-06-23 02:34:38",

  ...

]
```

Any suggestions and help will be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're JSON string is invalid. You can test it here: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Why two tags? C# or C++?

Comment: sorry I didn't put the whole json. Must have made some sort of mistake when shortening. I'm using .net libraries. So I guess correct tag would be c++

Answer (score 1):

Your web response is a json array,not a json object, so you'll need to pull out and parse each part individually. [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) Is probably the most popular option in C#. You'll need to define types for each other type of object the array contains (including child objects), though if they're POCO objects with public properties it's basically done automatically.

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
List<object> parts = new List<object>();
JArray array = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
parts.Add(array[0].ToObject<int>());
parts.Add(array[1].ToObject<DateTime>());
....
string formattedString = string.Join("|", parts);
```

If you can get the web service to give you a json object instead of the array, it becomes much easier to deserialize.

If you don't mind having the child-objects still in json format in the array, you could also just do:

```
formattedString=string.join("|",array);
```